# Why Spark is not recognizing this time format?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp

I get `null` for the timestamp `27-04-2021 14:11` with this code. What mistake am I doing? Why is the timestamp format string `DD-MM-yyyy HH:mm` not correct here?

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('27-04-2021 14:11',)], ['t'])
df = df.select(to_timestamp(df.t, 'DD-MM-yyyy HH:mm').alias('dt'))
display(df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`D` is for day of the year, and `d` is for day of the month.

Try this:

```py
df = df.select(F.to_timestamp(df.t, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm").alias("dt"))
```